# Variables get different values with same operations

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a basic understanding problem.

I tried reordering some code, and though the operations are supposedly equivalent I get different values.
I started with this line:

```
q, r, m = 10*q, 10*(r-m*t), (10*(3*q+r))//t - 10*m
```

and changed it to:

```
q*=10;  r=10*(r-m*t);   m= (10*(3*q+r))//t - 10*m;
```

(With initial values being q= 1, r= 6, t= 3, m= 3).

When I run only the second line, m gets value -30 (which is accurate if I followed the order-of-operations correctly), while running the first yields m= 0, which is what the program calls for.

What am I missing here? Does the comma method assign the value after all other assignments are done?

Comment: When using `x, y = foo, bar` syntax, all statements are executed before assigning the values to the variables. When using `x=foo; y=bar`, they are not.

Comment: So it was that simple.. I guess it is better in every way for the code 

Comment: Note that you can safely extract the `q` assignment. See my answer for details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your first snippet of code evaluates each expression on the right before assigning the results to your `q`, `r`, and `m` variables. Your second snippet instead assigns:

```
q*=10
r=10*(r-m*t)
```

-before evaluating:

```
m= (10*(3*q+r))//t - 10*m
```

which changes the result. If you must use the latter snippet, you'll need to introduce a temporary variable to store the original `q` and `r` variable values for usage in the final expression.

In fact, since `q` does not depend on either of the other variables, you could in fact assign its value last, keeping the other two in tract, to slightly simplify the expression:

```
r, m = 10*(r-m*t), (10*(3*q+r))//t - 10*m
q *= 10
```

Answer (score 1):

The assignments in `q, r, m = 10*q, 10*(r-m*t), (10*(3*q+r))//t - 10*m` are done independently by evaluating the right hand side of all the assignments without anyone affecting the others, meaning that when `(10*(3*q+r))//t - 10*m` is evaluated, the old value of `q` is used, not the new `10*q` (same with `r`). Notice that the only difference is in the value of `m`, which depends on the values of `r` and `q`, which aren't changing while `m` is being assigned.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, all the assignments use the values of the variables *before* any assignments are done.

In the second case, you're changing some variables before others (your later assignments are using the new values of the variables).

Compare `a, b = b, a` with `a = b; b = a`. This first will swap the values, the second will not.